# Nested relationships in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to register a new user with a **associated list of categories**.

I have a table called *categories* with list of unique categories (*category id, category name*).

I have a table called *accounts* with a list of users (*username, email, password* and list of associated *categories*).

I have a table called *account_categories* which is a mapping between *users* and *categories*.

Unfortunately when I am trying to create new user I receive an error that provided categories already exists.  I don't want to update *categories* table. I want to update *accounts* and *account_categories*.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**model.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryname = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.categoryname)

class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, age, categories, password=None, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

        if not kwargs.get('username'):
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username.')

        if not age:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid age.')

        if not categories:
            raise ValueError('Users must choose at least one intrest.')

        account = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email), age=age, categories=categories, username=kwargs.get('username')
        )

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()

        return account

    def create_superuser(self, email, age, categories, password, **kwargs):
        account = self.create_user(email=email, age=age, categories=categories, password=password, **kwargs)

        account.is_admin = True
        account.save()

        return account

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    age = models.SmallIntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['age', 'email']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'categoryname')

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'age', 'categories', 'password', 'confirm_password',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Account.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

**views.py**

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return (permissions.AllowAny(),)

        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsAccountOwner(),)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Account.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with received data. Probably this email / username has already been used.' + str(serializer.errors) + str(request.data) #+ str(serializer.is_valid())
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**database scheme**

http://postimg.org/image/o15ybcf9f/

**error**

http://postimg.org/image/4i5muo8fz/